# Python requests fill form of drop down menu

Tags: python, request, mechanize

I am trying to fill a form with python requests.  Some of the inputs are from a drop down menu like this

```
<td class="label">Format:</td>
            <td>
                <select id="format" name="format" onchange="Format()">
                    <option>---</option>
                    <option value="MP3">MP3</option>
                    <option value="FLAC">FLAC</option>
                    <option value="AAC">AAC</option>
                    <option value="AC3">AC3</option>
                    <option value="DTS">DTS</option>
                </select>
```

I usually use mechanize for this but since this is an SSL site I can make it work even with all the tricks found online. 
My question is: how can i make requests select for example MP3?  I know I have to use a dictionary like

```
data = {'title': 'Hello',  'name' : 'World'}
```

And so on..  But how to make it select from a menu??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the `select` element is `format` and the value should be one of `MP3/FLAC/AAC/AC3/DTS`, so you need to use exactly that:

```
data = {'title': 'Hello',  'name' : 'World', 'format': 'MP3'}
```

(for example).

Comment: Oh..  Was it that simple?

Comment: It shouldn't be complicated :)

Comment: Thanks!!  Will try it!!

Comment: Do u also know how upload a file using requests?

Comment: Regarding upload a file using requests - I'll check for you (but it's a different issue).

Comment: Check this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file